# Adding -erweise to adverbs

Tags: adverb

I come across a sentence:

> Der historische Dampfzug "Molli" fährt im Sommer regelmäßig Badegäste vom Ostseebad Kühlungsborn über Heiligendamm nach Bad Doberan.

Since the adverb `regelmäßig` modifies the verb `fahren` rather than an adjective, is it possible to add the suffix `-erweise` to make it `regelmäßigerweise`?

In general, can we add the suffix `-erweise` to any adverb, or can we do that only to some adverbs as specified in dictionaries?

Comment: Sounds very strange in this case.

Comment: Note, the suffix is "-weise". There's just an additional "er" between adjective roots and the suffix.

Comment: It sounds strange to add "-weise" to "regelmäßig". You find a couple of hits on Google but the rare number should tell you that it is uncommon. As with "regelmäßig" there are hundreds of words where you can add "-weise" but it would sound weird to native speakers. Perhaps, stick with these [examples](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Controller?wordFormationClass=Adjektiv-zu-Adverb-Ableitungen+mit+dem+Suffix+weise&entryClass=Cat+Adv&pageNo=1&pageSize=50&resultId=8ce861).

Comment: It sounds much better indeed if you say "In regelmäßiger Weise" instead of "regelmäßigerweise".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the suffix -weise, or -erweise, which is basically a Genitive plus weise, will create an adverb that often has a slightly different meaning than the adverb/adjective that you used for it. Thus, you shoudld only add it, if that is what you want to express.

> Er sagt mir freundlich, warum er mein Bier getrunken hat.

This *freundlich* is used as an adverb that directly describes how the action is performed... it could be translated as *in a friendly way*.

> Er sagt mir freundlicherweise, warum er mein Bier getrunken hat.

*Freundlicherweise* is more of a comment-adverb for the whole activity in this case. Other options for the same slot would be *zum Glück* or *endlich*. It has an ironic quality and I don't really know how to translate it to English. 
Anyway... the same idea applies to other adverbs like *großzügigerweise*, *dummerweise*, *glücklicherweise*, and so on. Without *-erweise* they quite literally qualify the verb, with *-erweise* they are more of a comment adverb.

While you can add -*erweise* to every lexical adjective in theory, it doesn't always make sense to do so. Either because the adverb is already commenting, or because a commenting adverb (which is what *-erweise* creates)  doesn't make much sense, or at least no difference to the one without the suffix. 
In case of *regelmäßigerweise* a reading as a comment adverb doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'd say these are roughly `He told me kindly, that ...` and `He was kind enough to tell me, that ...`.

Comment: I guess the last paragraph hardly holds for true adverbs like `manchmal`, `vielleicht` or `hinüber`.

Comment: I would have to think about this some more, but it seems to me that actually you add `-erweise` to an adjective to make it into an adverb. (Of course you do not have to do this in German.) After all `Weise` is a noun.

Comment: @Toscho: you're right... I changed it to "lexical adjective" if that makes sense

Comment: Und vielleicht kann man ja auch noch das Paar `regelmäßig/regelmäßigerweise` einbauen. Ich würde sagen, dass `regelmäßig` meist in der Art von `in gleichmäßigen Abständen` gebraucht wird, und `regelmäßigerweise` als `im normalen Verlauf der Dinge`.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz `regelmäßig` only means "according to some rule" this "rule" need not be "equidistance" although it is mainly used in such cases. `regelmäßigerweise` would rather mean "it is normal (according to some value system) to do this `regelmäßig`".